# Javafx, defaultCloseOperation

Tags: java, javafx

Как сделать так чтобы окно при нажатии на кнопку закрыть просто скрывалось?

> в работе приложения потребуется один и только один экземпляр этого окна, измените значение свойства `defaultCloseOperation` на `HIDE` (т.е. по нажатию на кнопку закрытия окна оно должно просто скрываться).

Это для Swing как это сделать для JavaFX.

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо обрабатывать евент closeRequest

```
this.stage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent - > {
    stage.hide();
});
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы приложение просто сворачивалось , необходимо сделать так

```
this.stage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent - > {
    stage.setIconified(true);
});
```